# Are there any other uses for Perlin Noise besides the obvious?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, noise

I have been looking into different algorithms lately and have read quite alot about perlin noise. It seems like the only thing people use it for is to generate textures (clouds/wood grain) or to distribute trees.

What else can Perlin Noise be used for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best treatise on Perlin noise and things you can do with it I know is in [Texturing and Modelling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122287606) by Ebert, but Hugo Elias put together a rather good collection of [pages on noise and other related subjects](https://web.archive.org/web/20160521081256/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/) some time back which is worth a look.

I used it extensively for creating realistic-looking landscapes when I wrote a series of Landscape Visualisation programs back in the late 90 early 2000s using various forms of Perlin noise processes to handle the terrain generation.  Many other programs do similar things - the wonderful [Terragen](http://www.planetside.co.uk/) for example.

I've also used it to apply realistic noise on top of other textures, for example to add 'roughness' to a [Photorealistic Textile plugin](http://www.geomantics.com/fabric.htm) for Photoshop.

Basically the charm of Perlin noise is that it's not random but turbulent, so in any case where you have a non-deterministic phenomenon it can be applied to give more 'natural' results.  Defiantly a set or routines that any programmer should be familiar with as its use is appropriate in many circumstances where people tend to reach for a random number generator. For example using a Perlin function to derive variations in velocity of some modelled moving entity in a game (say due to wind or some such) works far better than applying random changes.

Comment: Your examples were very helpful. I am a big fan of Hugo Elias' website. Also your last paragraph explained Uses for Perlin Noise beautifully.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget about [Worley noise](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=237267) too. It's a useful complement to Perlin.
The [paper itself](http://www.rhythmiccanvas.com/research/papers/worley.pdf) is here.

http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~nouanese/782/lab4/
http://www.flickr.com/photos/12739382@N04/2652571038/

Comment: Thanks for that! I had never heard of Worley noise before. I will have to have a play with it now

Answer (score 2):

I've already seen it for virtual character motion to seem more realistic.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used in 4 dimensions (i.e x,y,z, time) to create volumetric clouds that appear and disappear. Add a base movement vector that varies over time and you have wind too.

Answer (score 0):

One related use is for fractal generated terrains.